# Swift Charts Customize xAxis Label Position?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftcharts

[image]I can't seem to find a way to control where the xAxis labels in a Swift Chart are positioned, by default this code results in 2 xAxis labels in the center of the chart (as pictured).  I would like to customize this chart to show the date of the first sample on the far left and the date of the last sample on the far right, how can I accomplish this?

Chart {

```
  ForEach(buildChartRangedBarChartObjectsFrom(workoutStartDate: 
  workoutDetailViewModel.fullyLoadedWorkout?.startDate ?? Date(), workoutEndDate: 
  workoutDetailViewModel.fullyLoadedWorkout?.endDate ?? Date(), 
  customCyclingCadenceObjects: unwrappedCyclingCadenceObjects)) { 
  chartRangedBarChartObject in
      BarMark(
      x: .value("Date", chartRangedBarChartObject.periodStartDate),
      yStart: .value("Minimum Cadence During Minute", 
      chartRangedBarChartObject.minValue),
      yEnd: .value("Maximum Cadence During Minute", 
       chartRangedBarChartObject.maxValue),
       width: MarkDimension(integerLiteral: 5)
                                )
      .foregroundStyle(Color.teal.gradient)
                            }
                        }
      [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Do you just want *two* x axis labels, one at the start and one at the end?

Comment: Yes, I also tried using `                            .chartXAxis {
                                AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 4))
                            } ` but it looked the same as in my screenshot, so I would be happy with 2,  at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you are plotting data of each minute, you should add the `unit: .minute` parameter when creating your `PlottableValue` for the x axis. This makes it much easier for the system to automatically determine (aka "guess") which axis marks you want.

You can add the axis value labels like this:

```
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: .automatic(desiredCount: 2)) { value in
        AxisValueLabel(anchor: value.index == 1 ? .topTrailing : .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Since you want a label on each side, the labels will have different alignments relative to the value they are associated with. The left label is "left-aligned" and the right label is "right-aligned".

`.automatic(desiredCount: 2)` *should* always give you the values you want, but if you want to be extra sure, you can always just pass in an array of 2 `Date`s, extracted from your data.

Here is a complete example, which passes the labels you want directly as an array

```
struct Sample: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let start: Double
    let height: Double
    let time: Date
    
    var id: Date { time }
}

let data = (0..<30).map {
    Sample(start: .random(in: 10...20), height: .random(in: 10...16), time: Date().addingTimeInterval(Double($0) * 60))
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data) { sample in
            BarMark(
                x: .value("Time", sample.time, unit: .minute),
                yStart: .value("Min", sample.start),
                yEnd: .value("Max", sample.start + sample.height),
                width: 5
            )
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(values: [data.first!.time, data.last!.time]) { value in
                AxisValueLabel(
                    format: .dateTime.hour().minute(),
                    anchor: value.index == 1 ? .topTrailing : .topLeading
                )
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you `unit: .minute` is very helpful and by itself added a 3rd label to this chart.  Desired count of 4 still gives me 3 however.  And both solutions were you use `AxisValueLabel(anchor: value.index == 1 ? .topTrailing : .topLeading)`, the left label is plotted correctly but the right label is in the middle of the chart (and the date is in the 3rd quarter of the data - similar to the 3:11 in my screenshot above, when the last date should be around 3:27, as opposed to what I was trying to do, plot the last date in the far right.  

Comment: @GarySabo Okay, `automatic` doesn't like to behave then. I can't even reproduce your behaviour. Just pass in the two dates from the data as an array then. `[data.first!.time, date.last!.time]`.

Comment: @GarySabo Alternatively you can also use `stride` for the axis mark values. For example, if you have 30 minutes of data, do `.stride(by: .minute, count: 30)`.